# Series Problems

Tags: calculus

I was hoping someone could assist me with this problem. I'm confused as to what they are asking me for? I found that S is equal to 1/4 but what do they want for S sub n?

[image]

Comment: The partial sum of the series?

Comment: $S_n$ is the Nth partial sum. $S$ (sometimes $S_{\infty}$) is the infinite sum. Presumably they want you to find $S_n$ first so you can take the limit to find $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S_N \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n=5}^N \frac1{n(n-1)}$$